# Long polling JQUERY chat using sleep()

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, long-polling

The following code makes the web loading for like 10 minutes and I dont know why!

```
function chatheartbeat(){
    include("config.php");
    $useradn = $_SESSION['displayname'];
    $query = "select * from chat where (userbdn = '".$useradn."' AND isread = 1) order by id ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($query , $link);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($num_rows >= 1) {
        $items = array();
        $i='1';
        while($chat = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $items[$i]['from']=$chat['useradn'];
            $items[$i]['msg']=$chat['msg'];
            $items[$i]['timee']=date("H:i" ,$chat['timee']);
            $i++;
        }
        $query = "update chat set isread = 0 where userbdn = '".$useradn."' and isread = 1";
        mysql_query($query , $link);
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($items);
        exit;
    }else{
        sleep(2);
        chatheartbeat();
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would suspect that the response never ends, or rather, never (for a few minutes) starts sending.

Comment: @pst Until it hits a stack overflow :P

Comment: What does `config.php` look like? You should probably require it to make sure you get an sql connection.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling your function recursively and as the session variable does not change between the function calls, if it goes to the `else` part the first time, it will go there every time, creating a never ending loop.

By the way, if you want to use polling, you should set a timer in the client part (javascript) and not use a recursive function on the server side.

Comment: the second parameter is in the "config.php"

Comment: @user2124281 I figured as much and removed that part... See my comment below your question.

Comment: i did settimeout on the JS side, but i want to hold the requests untill there is new information.

Answer (score 2):

The function will never return until there are some results from the first select.

I would suggest that you return after n runs through (e.g. 5), even if there are no results. The client can then re-issue the ajax call to poll again.

Also, it's not a great idea to do this in a recursive manner. I would suggest doing this in a for loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you want to look at when performing any long polling techniques.

1. You need to exit after some predefined time period.  Waiting on the server until you have something to respond with will lead you to execution timeouts.
2. Know what is going on with your SESSION data.  PHP by default will use file based sessions and locks the file during the course of the request (unless you intervine)